# Selinux inode security struct allocation

Tags: security, linux-kernel, selinux, inode, lsm

i'm trying to understand allocation of `inode_security_struct` in Selinux. I looked for a source code of selinux and there is only one allocation of this struct [on line 230 in hooks.c file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/security/selinux/hooks.c#L225). This allocation is in LSM hook which is called when inode is created.

My question is how Selinux allocate inodes which were created before selinux init?

Thanks.